# How does `MonthNames` work for different cultures?

Tags: .net

When you call `System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames` you get a list of Month Names based on the current culture. If I change the current thread culture to a different one I should be able to get the month names back in that language. This seems to be working for French, but not for Japanese. What do I need to do so that I can get Japanese Months back? Is there something that I need to install for the OS, or do I need to install a .NET addon?

Comment: The answer will depend on your OS. What is it?

Comment: I am currently on Vista, but that might change, can you explain the differences between different OSes including server OSes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ja-JP");
foreach (var month in DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames)
{
    Console.WriteLine(month);
}
```

I don't have anything special installed--at least, not that I know of!

The [Wikipedia article on Japanese calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_calendar#Months) has an explanation of the Arabic numeral format.

Comment: For me it prints `1?`, `2?`, ..., `12?`

Comment: 1?, 2?...? Well, than your font can't display the kanji for month and therefore you see it as ?.

Comment: That's just a font issue. The default console font doesn't have those unicode characters defined, hence the ?. If you look at it using a font that supports the glyph (such as in the debugger, or use something like Lucida Sans Unicode in a windows forms app) you should see them.

Comment: You might need to install japanese fonts. In japanese month names mean only sth like "first month", "second month", and therefore they are written as number+kanji for "month".